# Email Segmentation in Service Console

Tags: email, service-cloud-console, email2case, casefeed

Agents in our Service Console are experiencing productivity issues due to the appending of emails in all blocks throughout the conversation. For example:

[image: Current email exchange]

Each block should contain one and only one email message, not the entire thread. Here is an example (from Zendesk) of what my organization is looking for:

[image: Desired email exchange]

I highlighted the delimiters in red to draw attention to the conversation's logical division.

I would like to replicate this division in our organization's Service Console. What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: Assuming this is for cases, you could theoretically develop your own email handler that would strip out the remainder of the message prior to it being inserted; however, you'd risk dropping the case thread Id so make sure you keep that thread ID somewhere in the emails you send out (maybe the subject line). Also, you could train your reps to strip out that part of the text prior to sending an email, that's a less than Ideal low tech way though.

Comment: This is indeed for cases! How would we go about developing our own email handler? 

I just got off of a call with Salesforce support and they said what I'm looking for needs to be custom built. There are no standard elements that support this feature; in fact, Salesforce support agents work in the same environment, too.

Frustrating, but it looks like I'm off to code land.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments, it looks like you'll need a custom handler:

[Custom Email Handlers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com)

The idea is to read the inbound email before it gets inserted and strip out the content you don't want.

As stated in my comment, you have to make sure to preserve the case thread ID in the email. You can try to intelligently add it back in after the signature in the email body or keep it in the subject line so that you don't risk stripping it out.

I went digging around in my gmail to see if I could find some example of stripping out the unwanted content but it seems that there is a bit of a variety in what you can expect to come in depending on the source. Emails from exchange seem to have a ton of Microsoft specific information in them.

Comment: After this implementation, OP will ask other questions with limitations using of email handler for email-to-case